# How to take a specific component from the API in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I started learning how to work with the API in vue js, how to take a certain condition from it, using the example https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json and updated conditions. I.e. I don't need to output all the APIs, but only the content of " updated":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ info }}</p>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      info: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response));
  }
})
```

Comment: Try `{{ info.data.time.updated }}`

Comment: Yes, its work, thx. But i have red text in console Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null"

(found in <Root>)

Comment: Because of `info` is null initially. so you can write `{{ info && info.data.time.updated }}` or `this.info = response.data.time.updated`

Comment: because `info` is `null` when it render for the first time